# How to restrict updating of some properties in a resource in a RESTful api?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am creating a web service (REST-ful API). I have a question regarding 
setting/updating certain properties on a resource.

The models in my application such as User have another class in the web 
layer for exposing it as a resource such as UserResource. The user 
resource does have a property such as `enabled` that determines whether 
the user is enabled or not. I don't know if it is only me thinking this 
but I think that a property like this should not be manipulated by 
regular users.

From an administration app this property would make sense but from an 
app consuming the services it doesn't. I have been looking on the API 
for Facebook and I see they don't allow access to all properties on a 
model through the resource. However does this mean that Facebook can't 
change these properties unless they modify their databases or do they 
have another set of resources for admin?

Do they have two APIs? One for management and another public API like 
the Open Graph API? I already have Spring ACL in my application, but 
that does not prevent the change of properties that only should be done 
by admins for instance.

Comment: you dont want to implement it throw code right ? you want API to handle this internally by setting some parameters of that properties right ?